# Adding Images to an ASPX page

Tags: c#, asp.net, image

I have an aspx page which I am pasting the code from. This page is a preview gallery which when I create a new gallery in my admin panel it auto updates to this page and places the text name I assign in the admin and assigns a page link which takes users to the actual gallery page for that preview... for instance I log in as admin and select manage free gallery.. enter the gallery name (for example" free preview") upload 8 or 9 images and a slideshow then hit submit. The gallery is then created and a link to that gallery is placed on my page for all free galleries. I want to not only have a link but an actual thumbnail image for these.. how would I do this given the code I am pasting below? I would also be willing to just eliminate the text link and go with a clickable thumbnail with a short description under it which actually would probably look better anyway.  Pasted ASPX Code follows:

ok so I cant post the code because I am new... any suggestions??? I can email code or post else where if anyone has some help info.

Thanks

Comment: Click the { } image in the edit text box to insert code blocks. Or you can just put 5 spaces then start typing.

Comment: without the code it might be difficult to understand

Answer (score 0):

How do you create your text link?  I assume you're using a [asp:Hyperlink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlink.aspx) control and you're just setting its Text and NavigateUrl properties?

Then you can do the same thing and also set the control's ImageUrl property to the URL path of the image.

Comment: The links are created automatically when I use the admin control. It uploads to a database with my description,images, and a video file. It is a image and video gallery that was created for the site. I log in as admin and hit manage free gallery then upload my text description which becomes the link as well as video and image files then it creates a page called /gallery/abc/1  /gallery/abc/2 etc.